# Stop Auto Text-Wrap on Paste of text with multiple lines

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

A situation that occurs for me multiple times a day is that I have multiple lines of text in, say, notepad that I would like to store in a single Excel cell. So I copy it from the other application, select the cell I want to paste it into and paste the text directly into the formula bar for that cell.

This stores all the text in the single cell, *however* Excel automatically expands that row to a huge size and auto-sets the `Alignment` > `Wrap Text` value to true and I have to manually select the cell and change the `Alignment` > `Wrap Text` value back to `False`.

I'm curious to know if there is a way / setting to change in Excel so that it won't auto-change the formatting in such a situation.

Any ideas / help?

Thanks!

Comment: does r-click > paste special : "values only" work ?

Comment: @p._phidot_, sadly not, because the text has line-feeds, I actually have to double-click the cell and paste it into the formula bad directly, not the cell. If I just paste (values only or not), it will break each linefeed into a new excel row and not paste it into a single cell.

Comment: I normally do [ Select All > Ctrl+J ] in notepad++, then I paste it in excel..

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it with using a VBA trigger on a specific worksheet.

You need to select the sheet you want to be performed and select the trigger "Change"

Then you need to write the following macro:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10").WrapText = False

End Sub
```

Every time you change a cell in the worksheet this would automatically turn back the wrap text property to false.
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkRi1.png)